# WebSite Scraper: How to make my Parallel Thread print to seperate output locations

Tags: multithreading, perl, file-io

I'm putting together a program that can store data 5 or 6 webpages into an array, and then extract the 'the Titles' from each page. So far, it retrieves the pages content except when I try to have the extracted 'Titles' printed. I can only print to one output file.

When I googled for a solution, it took me down every road except for my question. Can someone suggest some ways I can print the 'Titles' of each page to separate output files?

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;

use threads;
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
use WWW::Mechanize;

my @threads = ();
my @urls    = qw(http://site1.com http://site2.com);

foreach my $url ( @urls ) {
  push @threads, async {

    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
    printf( "Loaded: %s \n", $url );
    my $res       = $mech->get( $url );
    my $ducktales = $mech->title;

    $_->join for @threads;

    open( DATA, ">C:/Users/User/Desktop/11.txt" ) or die "cant";
    print DATA $ducktales;
  };
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't `use warnings` as well as the shebang line `-w` switch. You should choose one or the other, and your choice should be `use warnings`.  In addition you must *always* `use strict` at the top of every Perl program you write.

Comment: The [documentation for `threads`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#WARNING) says *"The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged."* You should use [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's look at your [open](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#open):

```
open(DATA,">C:/Users/User/Desktop/11.txt")
```

You are using a bareword handle, `DATA`. Such handles are package global meaning if you opened different files at different points in your code, each new `open` would cause the previously opened file to be closed.

On top of that, the `DATA` filehandle is special, and you should probably not trample on it.

So, first, use lexical filehandles:

```
open my $data, ...
```

Next, if an error occurs, you do not show the name of the file or the error message, accessible through `$!`. This means you are only thinking in terms of single, global filehandles.

```
open my $data, '>', $data_file
   or die "Cannot open '$data_file' for writing: $!";
```

Now, where does `$data_file` come from? If I understand correctly, you want one data file per URL. Therefore, it makes sense to name the data file based on the URL, restricting the name to consist of some safe subset of characters.

For now, forget about threads, and write the subroutine that will take a URL, fetch it, extract the title, and write it to a file based on the URL:

```
sub extract_and_write_title {
    my $url = shift;
    # fetch document
    # extract title
    # if success, open file named based on URL
    # write title, close file
    return;
}
```

Now, in your main loop, you can create threads based on this routine:

```
 push @threads, threads->create(
      \&extract_and_write_title,
      $url,
 );
```

You can fill in the blanks. As a rule, I do not give random people in the intarwebs complete scraping solutions.

Comment: *" I do not give random people in the intarwebs complete scraping solutions"* Bravo!